# How to include batch size in pytorch basic example?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am new to pytorch. The following is the basic example of using **nn** module to train a simple one-layer model with some random data ([from here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html))

```
import torch
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

x = torch.randn(N, D_in)
y = torch.randn(N, D_out)

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(D_in, H),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(H, D_out),
)
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
for t in range(500):
    y_pred = model(x)

    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
    print(t, loss.item())

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

As far as I understand, the batch size is equal to 1 in the example, in other words, a single point (out of 64) is used to calculate gradients and update parameters. My question is: how to modify this example to train the model with the batch size greater than one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact `N` is the batch size. So you just need to modify `N` currently its set to 64. So you have in every training batch 64 vectors with size / dim `D_in`.

I checked the link you posted, you can also take a look at the comments - there is some explanation too :)

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np

# N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
# H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

# Create random input and output data
x = np.random.randn(N, D_in)
y = np.random.randn(N, D_out)

# Randomly initialize weights
w1 = np.random.randn(D_in, H)
w2 = np.random.randn(H, D_out)

learning_rate = 1e-6
for t in range(500):
    # Forward pass: compute predicted y
    h = x.dot(w1)
    h_relu = np.maximum(h, 0)
    y_pred = h_relu.dot(w2)

    # Compute and print loss
    loss = np.square(y_pred - y).sum()
    print(t, loss)

    # Backprop to compute gradients of w1 and w2 with respect to loss
    grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y)
    grad_w2 = h_relu.T.dot(grad_y_pred)
    grad_h_relu = grad_y_pred.dot(w2.T)
    grad_h = grad_h_relu.copy()
    grad_h[h < 0] = 0
    grad_w1 = x.T.dot(grad_h)

    # Update weights
    w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
    w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2
```

Comment: If `N` is the batch size, where is the number of training examples defined?

Comment: @oezguensi It is `N` too - there is only *one* batch here, with batch size `64`. This example iterates just 500 times over the same batch: *number_of_training_examples  = num_batches \* batch_size*, thus *1 \* 64 = 64*

Comment: That seems quite useless. Why should we iterate over the same training examples again and again. Is it just the example that is wrong, because of simplicity or am I missing something?

Comment: @oezguensi Yes, in reality you wouldn't do that. But I guess it is just for illustration purposes how dimensions work out within a batch while keeping it simple.

Comment: is `t` the number of epochs in this sample example? I believe there needs to be another for loop through `training_num` right after `for t in range(500):`

Comment: @FäridAlijani So this is a bad example for epochs. The description of `t` in this context would be the number of iterations / steps. So the number of times you update the weights. An epoch is usually referred making a complete iteration over your training data. As this is the case here as well `t` also stands for epochs since `x` is all the training data we have. But you are right, normally when training in epochs you would have an iterator for the epochs and an iterator that iterates over the training data. But in this minimal example this second iterator has only one iteration.

Answer (score 9):

To include batch size in PyTorch basic examples, the easiest and cleanest way is to use PyTorch `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` and `torch.utils.data.TensorDataset`.

> Dataset stores the samples and their corresponding labels, and DataLoader wraps an iterable around the Dataset to enable easy access to the samples.

`DataLoader` will take care of creating batches for you.

Building on your question, there is a complete code snippet, where we iterate over a dataset of 10000 examples for 2 epochs with a batch size of 64:

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset


# Create the dataset with N_SAMPLES samples
N_SAMPLES, D_in, H, D_out = 10000, 1000, 100, 10

x = torch.randn(N_SAMPLES, D_in)
y = torch.randn(N_SAMPLES, D_out)

# Define the batch size and the number of epochs
BATCH_SIZE = 64
N_EPOCHS = 2

# Use torch.utils.data to create a DataLoader 
# that will take care of creating batches 
dataset = TensorDataset(x, y)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)

# Define model, loss and optimizer
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(D_in, H),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(H, D_out),
)

loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

# Get the dataset size for printing (it is equal to N_SAMPLES)
dataset_size = len(dataloader.dataset)

# Loop over epochs
for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}\n-------------------------------")

    # Loop over batches in an epoch using DataLoader
    for id_batch, (x_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(dataloader):

        y_batch_pred = model(x_batch)

        loss = loss_fn(y_batch_pred, y_batch)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Every 100 batches, print the loss for this batch
        # as well as the number of examples processed so far 
        if id_batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), (id_batch + 1)* len(x_batch)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{dataset_size:>5d}]")
```

The output should be something like:

```
Epoch 1
-------------------------------
loss: 643.433716  [   64/10000]
loss: 648.195435  [ 6464/10000]
Epoch 2
-------------------------------
loss: 613.619873  [   64/10000]
loss: 625.018555  [ 6464/10000]
```