# How to specify the batch_size in PyTorch Sequantial model?

Tags: pytorch, sequential, batchsize

I have a Sequential model in PyTorch:

```
model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Embedding(alphabet_size, 64),
        nn.LSTM(64, ...),
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.Linear(...),
        nn.Softmax()
    )
```

I would like to force the batch size to Embedding layer:

```
nn.Embedding(alphabet_size, 64)
```

as in Keras:

```
Embedding(alphabet_size, 64, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, time_steps)))
```

How to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer to your question.
The example already available below

[PyTorch sequential model and batch_size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735001/how-to-include-batch-size-in-pytorch-basic-example)