# How to feed batches into torch.nn.Linear so that it works

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

There are quite a few questions about using nn.Linear with batched data, if I understand answers correctly the first dimension of the input tensor contains current batch items.

Taken [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69389898/656449) as base I tried to model parabola,like this:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

# Create the dataset with N_SAMPLES samples
# N_SAMPLES, D_in, H, D_out = 10000, 1000, 100, 10
N_SAMPLES, D_in, H, D_out = 1000, 1, 10, 1

# x = torch.randn(N_SAMPLES, D_in)
x = torch.arange(0, N_SAMPLES, dtype=torch.float32).view(N_SAMPLES, -1)
# y = torch.randn(N_SAMPLES, D_out)
y = x ** 2

# Define the batch size and the number of epochs
BATCH_SIZE = 1
N_EPOCHS = 100

# Use torch.utils.data to create a DataLoader
# that will take care of creating batches
dataset = TensorDataset(x, y)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)

# Define model, loss and optimizer
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(D_in, H),
    torch.nn.ELU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(H, H),
    torch.nn.ELU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(H, H),
    torch.nn.ELU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(H, H),
    torch.nn.ELU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(H, D_out),
)

loss_fn = torch.nn.HuberLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), 0.001)

# Get the dataset size for printing (it is equal to N_SAMPLES)
dataset_size = len(dataloader.dataset)

# Loop over epochs
for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}\n-------------------------------")

    # Loop over batches in an epoch using DataLoader
    for id_batch, (x_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(dataloader):

        y_batch_pred = model(x_batch)

        loss = loss_fn(y_batch_pred, y_batch)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Every 100 batches, print the loss for this batch
        # as well as the number of examples processed so far
        if id_batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), (id_batch + 1)* len(x_batch)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{dataset_size:>5d}]")

with torch.no_grad():
    model.eval()
    predicted_y = []
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        predicted_y.extend(model(X.view(X.size()[0], -1)))

    plot_array(predicted_y)
```

when BATCH_SIZE set to 1 it works fine:

[image]

but when BATCH_SIZE increases it gets screwed and turns into straight line when it's more than 10.

Why is it so? Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: This question seems to be about choosing the right batch size for the model, so I think it's better suited in Cross Validated or AI SO. Nevertheless, that's my answer.